# RestEasy : How to send an easy POST request with parameters and api key

Tags: java, resteasy

I'm a beginner and I'm a little bit lost with Resteasy

I'd like to send a post request with an URL similar to this : http://myurl.com/options?value=3name=picture

```
String myValue = "3";
String myName = "picture";
String key = "topsecret";
```

I'm not too sure about what's coming. I've seen several tutorial classes (not very clear to me) and another way similar to this

```
final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl<>();
queryParams.add("value", myValue);
queryParams.add("name", myPicture);
final ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url).queryParams(queryParams);;
final Builder builder = target.request();
```

When I write I have loads of warning. Is it the right way do it ? What about the API key ?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: I will but some expected bugs have to be corrected before I can check it works(tks)

Comment: It does work, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you must check the documentation of the API you want to consume regarding how the API key must be sent to the server. *Not all APIs follow the same approach.*

For example purposes, let's assume that the API key must be sent in the `X-Api-Key` header. It's a *non standard* and I've made it up just to demonstrate how to use the client API.

So you can have the following:

```java
// Create a client
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

// Define a target
WebTarget target = client.target("http://myurl.com/options")
                         .queryParam("value", "3")
                         .queryParam("name", "picture");

// Perform a request to the target
Response response = target.request().header("X-Api-Key", "topsecret")
                          .post(Entity.text(""));

// Process the response
// This part is up to you

// Close the response
response.close();

// Close the client
client.close();
```

The above code uses the JAX-RS API, which is implemented by RESTEasy. You'd better use [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instead of [`ResteasyClient`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.1.4.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClient.html) whenever possible to ensure portability with other implementations.

The above code also assumes that you want to send an *empty text* in the request payload. *Modify it accordingly.*

[`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) instances that contain an un-consumed entity input stream *should be closed*. This is typical for scenarios where only the response headers and the status code are processed, *ignoring the response entity*.

---

Going beyond the scope of the question, bear in mind that [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances are *heavy-weight* objects that manage the underlying client-side communication infrastructure. Hence initialization as well as disposal of a [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance may be a rather expensive operation.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) advises to create only a *small number* of [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances and *reuse them when possible*. It also states that [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances must be *properly closed before being disposed* to avoid leaking resources.